# Código Css alterando layout inteiro da página

Tags: html, css

Criei uma imagem com efeito de `hover` que mostra uma listagem em cima da mesma ao passar o mouse, só que o código está alterando o layout inteiro.

CSS:

```
div a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 0px;
    display:block;
}
ul {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #EA3F3F;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    display: none;
}
ul li ul li {
    background: #555;
    display: inline;
    font-size:23px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
    opacity:1;
}
ul li ul li a {
    display:block !important;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #475DDA;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img align='left' src='http://oi58.tinypic.com/2lxrh2.jpg' />
            <ul>
                <p>
                    <li> <a href='#'>0 - 9</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#'>A - C</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#'>D - F</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#'>G - I</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#'>J - L</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#'>M - O</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#'>P - R</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#'>S - U</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#'>V - X</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#'>Y - Z</a>
                    </li>
                </p>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Entendo que o problema é no .css  onde

```
div a {
ul li {
ul li:hover {
ul li:hover ul {
ul li ul {
```

Estão alterando todo o layout, seria possível fazer com que esse código seja interpretado só nessa imagem?

Se não, como eu passo essas linhas dos css para funcionarem somente na foto? Tentei por id na div mas não consigo fazer os efeitos no `.css` alterarem a lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma class na sua `div` principal e setar o `css` a partir da mesma. Isolando assim o style da `div` do resto do layout. Seu código ficaria assim:

HTML:

```
<div class="divComImagem">
 <!--Aqui o resto de seu conteúdo-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divComImagem a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 0px;
    display:block;
}
.divComImagem ul {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.divComImagem ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.divComImagem ul li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #EA3F3F;
}
.divComImagem ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.divComImagem ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    display: none;
}
.divComImagem ul li ul li {
    background: #555;
    display: inline;
    font-size:23px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
    opacity:1;
}
.divComImagem ul li ul li a {
    display:block !important;
}
.divComImagem ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #475DDA;
}
```

Segue o [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/6eva13ys/)

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado eu até entendia utilizar a class div e isolar mas não estava fazendo certo então tem como fazer .divComImagem ul li ul li {
Achei que antes da abertura era só o id :)